# ProtoBuf generated java classes does not work correctly with Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers, grpc, spring-el

I have folowing proto files

```
message Department {
 string deptName =1;
}
message Person {
 string name =1;
Department dept=2;
}
```

When the java classes getting created you can see the field names will be something like this.

name_  and dept_

but protoBuf provides the getName() and getDept() methods from that we can access the values of Person class.

But somehow when I try to filter these using Spring Expression Language (SpEL) I am getting below exceptions.

The error message "EL1008E: Property or field 'dept_' cannot be found on object of type 'com.test.Person' - maybe not public or not valid?" is related to Spring Expression Language (SpEL) and indicates that the specified property or field (dept_ in this case) cannot be found on the object of type com.test.Person.

Comment: "But somehow when I try to filter these using Spring Expression Language" - you haven't shown how you've tried to do that. I don't know anything about SpEL myself, but I'd *expect* it to be based on properties rather than the private fields which should be seen as implementation details. It sounds like you're passing in `dept_` in the expression, instead of `dept` (from which I'd expect SpEL to discover `getDept()`). Please provide a [mcve].